# How to setup different env variables for different environments in CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration, react-native, react-native-ios, circleci

I want to use different environment variables for different environments in `CircleCI`. For example, there is `WEBSITE_URL` variable and I want it to be different for production builds and other builds. I setup `PROD_WEBSITE_URL` and `DEV_WEBSITE_URL` inside CircleCI Project settings (environment variables).

My idea was to use this code in `config.yml` file, but when I tested this code, variable was undefined in the app.

```
 - run:
      name: 'Setup Environment Variables'
      command: |
          if [[ $CIRCLE_BRANCH == "main" ]] ; then
            echo "export WEBSITE_URL=$PROD_WEBSITE_URL" >> $BASH_ENV
          else
            echo "export WEBSITE_URL=$DEV_WEBSITE_URL" >> $BASH_ENV
          fi
```

P.S: I have `React Native` app, I use `react-native-dotenv` for env variables locally.

Comment: One word: ew. Why is this the acceptable approach for such a basic use case?

Comment: @AlxVallejo how would you implement it differently?

Comment: Hi @Lucky_girl

How did you access this environment variable inside your React Native Code base, I am stuck at this point trying to understand how to get this value. Its always undefined when I use ```process.env['BACK_END_BASE_URL']``` or ```process.env.BACK_END_BASE_URL```

Comment: @AppyMango I do in the file like this import { WEBSITE_URL } from '@env';  and then in the code  const mainUrl = `${WEBSITE_URL}`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `source $BASH_ENV` at the end of your command as following:

```
 - run:
      name: 'Setup Environment Variables'
      command: |
          if [[ $CIRCLE_BRANCH == "main" ]] ; then
            echo "export WEBSITE_URL=$PROD_WEBSITE_URL" >> $BASH_ENV
          else
            echo "export WEBSITE_URL=$DEV_WEBSITE_URL" >> $BASH_ENV
          fi
          source $BASH_ENV
```

Comment: How did you access this environment variable inside your React Native Code base, I am stuck at this point trying to understand how to get this value. Its always undefined when I use ```process.env['BACK_END_BASE_URL']``` or ```process.env.BACK_END_BASE_URL```

Comment: @AppyMango this is not related - open a separate SO or find me at devopscommunity.org - will help.

Comment: @AppyMango Did you find the solution how to use in the codebase?